# Left join with linq query does not work with null columns in datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I have two Datatables on which I'm performing a left join using linq. It does work when I'm using JOIN, but since it has some null values in the resulted data when used the left join, it doesn't work. Below is the code

```
DataTable dt1 = user.getData();
DataTable dt2 = user.getOldData();
var results = from p2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
              join p1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              on p2["XPNNUM"].ToString() equals (string)p1["pid"]
              into a
              from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()

              select new
              {
                    XPNNUM = p2["XPNNUM"].ToString(),
                    XPNNAM = (string)p2["XPNNAM"],
                    XPNGRD = (string)p2["XPNGRD"],

                    user_id = b["user_id"].ToString(),
                    firstname = b["firstname"].ToString(),
                    usertype = b["usertype"].ToString(),
                    subid = b["subid"].ToString(),

              };
```

If the Data is like below, this won't work and it' gives a object reference not set to an instance error.

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
| XPNNUM | XPNNAM | XPNGRD | user_id | firstname | usertype | subid |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
|     12 | Test   |      4 | null    | null      | null     | null  |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

Is there any better way to do the same? Can't do this in the SQL end since datatables are coming from two different sources.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add null-checks to fields, which can be null (`user_id`, `firstname`, `usertype`, `subid`) as following:

```
DataTable dt1 = user.getData();
DataTable dt2 = user.getOldData();
var results = from p2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
          join p1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
          on p2["XPNNUM"].ToString() equals (string)p1["pid"]
          into a
          from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()

          select new
          {
                XPNNUM = p2["XPNNUM"].ToString(),
                XPNNAM = (string)p2["XPNNAM"],
                XPNGRD = (string)p2["XPNGRD"],

                user_id = b?["user_id"]?.ToString(),
                firstname = b?["firstname"]?.ToString(),
                usertype = b?["usertype"]?.ToString(),
                subid = b?["subid"]?.ToString(),

          };
```

Comment: It's not working. Still gives the error "{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object}"

Comment: I guess the problem here is this ,--- b["user_id"] , if there's any other way to get the value in that column it should work.

Comment: Ok, b is null then, so check it also: `b?["user_id"]?.ToString()`